# Can you export an Angular component into Sketch?

Tags: angular, reactjs, sketchapp

I was looking over how Airbnb introduced a way to export React Components into Sketch. Is this possible for Angular Components? If so where can I find the reference to do that?

Comment: You can in Angular 6 . [Version 6 of Angular Now Available](https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4)

Answer (score 0):

Dynatrace has made an open-source project to do exactly that. https://github.com/Dynatrace/sketchmine